# Remote does match the VCS endpoint for logrus package

Tags: go, glide-golang

Something weird is happening here, and I can't figure it out.

I'm using glide for my dependencies, and there's one package giving me grief. I added the github.com/sirupsen/logrus package for logging, and then ran `glide up`. This happened:

```
[INFO]  Downloading dependencies. Please wait...
[INFO]  --> Fetching updates for github.com/bgentry/speakeasy.
[INFO]  --> Fetching updates for github.com/sirupsen/logrus.
[ERROR] Update failed for github.com/sirupsen/logrus: The Remote does not match the VCS endpoint
[ERROR] Could not update packages: The Remote does not match the VCS endpoint
```

Now I did a bunch of googling, and this is usually related to repos changing names or destination, but this didn't happen in this case. So what might be causing it?

Here's my `glide.lock`:

```
hash: fb99f00e96f2316b9acbe5892497bbc46e936bd2822dba68e5bf1aef553d63cc
updated: 2017-03-12T18:55:33.370219633Z
imports:
- name: github.com/fatih/structs
  version: a720dfa8df582c51dee1b36feabb906bde1588bd
- name: github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify
  version: a904159b9206978bb6d53fcc7a769e5cd726c737
- name: github.com/hashicorp/errwrap
  version: 7554cd9344cec97297fa6649b055a8c98c2a1e55
- name: github.com/hashicorp/go-cleanhttp
  version: 3573b8b52aa7b37b9358d966a898feb387f62437
- name: github.com/hashicorp/go-multierror
  version: ed905158d87462226a13fe39ddf685ea65f1c11f
- name: github.com/hashicorp/go-rootcerts
  version: 6bb64b370b90e7ef1fa532be9e591a81c3493e00
- name: github.com/hashicorp/hcl
  version: 372e8ddaa16fd67e371e9323807d056b799360af
  subpackages:
  - hcl/ast
  - hcl/parser
  - hcl/scanner
  - hcl/strconv
  - hcl/token
  - json/parser
  - json/scanner
  - json/token
- name: github.com/hashicorp/vault
  version: ebb798ec1b2c93a4607d44438c6f56438a17b4cc
  subpackages:
  - api
  - helper/compressutil
  - helper/jsonutil
- name: github.com/inconshreveable/mousetrap
  version: 76626ae9c91c4f2a10f34cad8ce83ea42c93bb75
- name: github.com/magiconair/properties
  version: b3b15ef068fd0b17ddf408a23669f20811d194d2
- name: github.com/mitchellh/go-homedir
  version: b8bc1bf767474819792c23f32d8286a45736f1c6
- name: github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure
  version: db1efb556f84b25a0a13a04aad883943538ad2e0
- name: github.com/pelletier/go-buffruneio
  version: df1e16fde7fc330a0ca68167c23bf7ed6ac31d6d
- name: github.com/pelletier/go-toml
  version: d1fa2118c12c44e4f5004da216d1efad10cb4924
- name: github.com/sethgrid/pester
  version: 2c5fb962da6113d0968907fd81dba3ca35151d1c
- name: github.com/spf13/afero
  version: 72b31426848c6ef12a7a8e216708cb0d1530f074
  subpackages:
  - mem
- name: github.com/spf13/cast
  version: d1139bab1c07d5ad390a65e7305876b3c1a8370b
- name: github.com/spf13/cobra
  version: fcd0c5a1df88f5d6784cb4feead962c3f3d0b66c
- name: github.com/spf13/jwalterweatherman
  version: fa7ca7e836cf3a8bb4ebf799f472c12d7e903d66
- name: github.com/spf13/pflag
  version: 5ccb023bc27df288a957c5e994cd44fd19619465
- name: github.com/spf13/viper
  version: 5ed0fc31f7f453625df314d8e66b9791e8d13003
- name: golang.org/x/net
  version: e90d6d0afc4c315a0d87a568ae68577cc15149a0
  subpackages:
  - http2
  - http2/hpack
  - lex/httplex
- name: golang.org/x/sys
  version: 8f0908ab3b2457e2e15403d3697c9ef5cb4b57a9
  subpackages:
  - unix
- name: golang.org/x/text
  version: 2910a502d2bf9e43193af9d68ca516529614eed3
  subpackages:
  - transform
  - unicode/norm
- name: gopkg.in/yaml.v2
  version: 53feefa2559fb8dfa8d81baad31be332c97d6c77
testImports: []
```

I've tried deleting the `glide.lock` and `glide.yaml` and starting from scratch, with no relief. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`import "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"` is correct. To bust the glide cache, do `glide install --force`

Answer (score 1):

This was really stupid in the end.

The sirupsen package expects your import to have an upper case s at the beginning of Sirupse in the import.

I changed this:

```
import "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
```

to this

```
import "github.com/Sirupsen/logrus"
```

And it worked!

Comment: Thanks, this was very annoying to debug! :D